# WebLogic session count not replicating

Tags: jvm, weblogic

In WebLogic admin console we can see the number of active sessions by following the below link

```
admin console -> environment -> server -> servername -> deployment -> webapplication -> monitoring -> webapplication -> sessions
```

If I open a new session, it is increasing the value.
But when I logout and close the session (close the browser) it is not decreasing the session count. I waited for 15 minutes.

And one more is we can see TotalGarbageCollectionCount that is The number of garbage collection runs that have occurred since the Virtual Machine was started, in JRockit JVM but I am using hotspot in this server. How to know the GC count and TotalGarbageCollectionTime?

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable the session replication option in weblogic console...

Logon to admin console

go to clusters -> goto advanced tab -> enable the session replication option